# Adding annotations from GeoFire query only drops one pin

Tags: firebase, geofire

I can only get one pin to stay on the map when I run this GeoFire query.  It places all of them briefly, but then thinly one that remains is the last one. I want all annotations to stay on the map. This is the code:

```
if location != nil {
        let center = location.coordinate
        // Query location by region
        let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.1, 0.1)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(center, span)
        regionQuery = geoFire?.query(with: region)


        queryHandle = regionQuery.observe(.keyEntered, with: { (key, location) in
           //print("Key '\(key)' entered the search area and is at location '\(location)'")


            self.annot.coordinate = (location!.coordinate)
            self.annot.title = key
            self.mapView.addAnnotation(self.annot)
            print(self.annot.coordinate)
           })

    queryHandle = regionQuery.observe(.keyExited, with: { (key, location) in
    })

}
```